# Translating SVG text in css - why do my text boxes move from the origin instead of their starting location?

Tags: css, svg, transform, transition, translate

So,

I have a little hover animation I am doing.  But I am having some issues with using "transform: translate".  **I want my letters to move from location 1 to location 2, with a translate and have a transition set so they appear animated**. The good news is that the letters actually end up where I want them to, their final location is correct. The problem is that for some reason the animation switches its starting location (location 1) from the center of the screen to the upper left hand corner (the origin) upon hover.

**I am looking for a pure css solution.**  I don't care about keeping the matrices, if you need to get rid of them that is fine.  I do want them to be svg text, however.

I think this mistake comes from me not fully understanding the svg coordinate system.  I've tried to read about things, I've searched, but I don't understand.  Can someone who is experienced in svg and css help me out?

This is my codepen: http://codepen.io/ihatecoding/pen/mPBWWo?editors=1100

Here is the HTML:

```
    <a href="abcd.html" class="abcdSVG">
    <div> 
      <svg version="1.1"
             id="Layer_1"  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
             xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="76.828px"
             height="74.758px" viewBox="0 0 76.828 74.758" enable-background="new 0 0 76.828 74.758" xml:space="preserve">
     <text id="abcd-A" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 32.1255 36.3169)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="9">A</text>
              <text id="abcd-B" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 38.8467 36.3169)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="9">B</text>
              <text id="abcd-C" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 32.1313 43.7246)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="9">C</text>
              <text id="abcd-D" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 37.4658 43.7246)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="9">D</text>
    </svg>
    </div>
</a>
```

This is my CSS:

```
text{stroke:Red;}
 .abcdSVG svg:hover #abcd-A{transform: translate(18px, 28px);}
 .abcdSVG svg:hover #abcd-B{transform: translate(46px, 28px);}
 .abcdSVG svg:hover #abcd-C{transform: translate(18px, 50px);}
 .abcdSVG svg:hover #abcd-D{transform: translate(46px, 50px);}

 .abcdSVG svg #abcd-A,
 .abcdSVG svg #abcd-B,
 .abcdSVG svg #abcd-C,
 .abcdSVG svg #abcd-D,
 .abcdSVG svg:hover #abcd-A,
 .abcdSVG svg:hover #abcd-B,
 .abcdSVG svg:hover #abcd-C,
 .abcdSVG svg:hover #abcd-D

 {
    transition: 500ms;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: 500ms;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the `transform` in your CSS over-writes (replaces) the `transform` attributes that are already in your elements.

You need to move the transforms out of your SVG and make them the initial state for the elements in the CSS.

```css
text{stroke:Red;}

.abcdSVG svg #abcd-A{transform: translate(32.1255px, 36.3169px);}
.abcdSVG svg #abcd-B{transform: translate(38.8467px, 36.3169px);}
.abcdSVG svg #abcd-C{transform: translate(32.1313px, 43.7246px);}
.abcdSVG svg #abcd-D{transform: translate(37.4658px, 43.7246px);}

.abcdSVG svg:hover #abcd-A{transform: translate(18px, 28px);}
.abcdSVG svg:hover #abcd-B{transform: translate(46px, 28px);}
.abcdSVG svg:hover #abcd-C{transform: translate(18px, 50px);}
.abcdSVG svg:hover #abcd-D{transform: translate(46px, 50px);}

.abcdSVG svg #abcd-A,
.abcdSVG svg #abcd-B,
.abcdSVG svg #abcd-C,
.abcdSVG svg #abcd-D,
.abcdSVG svg:hover #abcd-A,
.abcdSVG svg:hover #abcd-B,
.abcdSVG svg:hover #abcd-C,
.abcdSVG svg:hover #abcd-D
{
   transition: 500ms;
   -webkit-transition: 500ms;

   transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<span> why do my letters jump here <br>⇩   on hover?
<a href="abcd.html" class="abcdSVG">
    <div> 
      <svg version="1.1"
            id="Layer_1"  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="76.828px"
            height="74.758px" viewBox="0 0 76.828 74.758" enable-background="new 0 0 76.828 74.758" xml:space="preserve">
              <text id="abcd-A" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="9">A</text>
              <text id="abcd-B" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="9">B</text>
              <text id="abcd-C" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="9">C</text>
              <text id="abcd-D" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="9">D</text>
    </svg>
    </div>
</a>
```